# Buttons from superclass are still in subclasses

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

In my constructor in the superclass I have buttons that lead to other subclasses.  However, these subclasses also inherit these buttons even though they aren't in their constructors.  How can I remove these buttons from showing up in my subclasses?  I'm using javax.swing.

Ok here is a code example. I'm pretty sure I am doing OOP completely wrong...

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Big extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    static private JPanel p1;
    static private JButton b1;    
    public Big(){    
        setSize(700,400);
        p1 = new JPanel();
        b1 = new JButton("Go to subclass");
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        p1.add(b1);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == b1){
            setVisible(false); 
            Small subclass = new Small();
        }
    }
}
```

2nd class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Small extends Big implements ActionListener
{
    static private JButton b2;
    static private JPanel p2;
    public Small(){    
        setSize(700,400);
        p2 = new JPanel();
        b2 = new JButton("Hello!");
        p2.add(b2);
        add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){}
}
```

Comment: Add some code, please.

Comment: You can't remove things from a superclass when you subclass it. Could be there's a way around it but without your code we don't know how you can change it.

Comment: This smells like you may be using inheritance inappropriately. Why are you subclassing this class to begin with?

Comment: He still can use buttonX.setVisible(false) in constructor, but it may not be the appropriate answer to its problem...

Comment: @kmas added example code

Comment: Your button and panel fields should not be static. With static fields, creation of additional instances of Big or Small is going to overwrite the field values and damage the previous instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors must always call the constructor of the superclass as the first thing they do. If you don't write this explicitly, the compiler inserts the call automatically (assuming that there is a no-argument constructor in the superclass to call; otherwise it demands you do it yourself). So the actual beginning of Small's constructor looks like this:

```
public Small() {
    super(); // call Big() constructor
    setSize(700,400);
    ...
```

That's why it appears to inherit the buttons "even though they aren't in their constructors".

One way you could circumvent this is to move the code that creates the panels and buttons into a createGUI() method which you could override. Unlike constructors, methods do not have to call any superclass methods if they don't want to:

```
public class Big extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    ...

    public Big() {
        createGUI();
    }

    protected void createGUI() {
        // Init buttons of Big here.
    }
}

public class Small extends Big {
    // This constructor is optional; if you remove it, the
    // compiler will insert one that looks exactly like this.
    public Small() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void createGUI() {
        // Init buttons of Small here.
        // Big's constructor calls this method, but it has been overridden,
        // so Big's implementation of this method will not execute for
        // instances of Small (unless you call super.createGUI(); on purpose).
    }
}
```

I'm not suggesting this change is a good idea and I don't think it is. As others have pointed out, it's not clear why Small extends Big when it doesn't seem to want to inherit Big's code, or its behavior, or its fields. I just wanted to explain why the superclass buttons were appearing at all. It's because constructors *must* call the superclass constructor.

Comment: Ugh, calling non-final methods in a constructor can lead to problems.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code you've posted, I see no reason for using inheritance. I suggest that you simply don't inherit, and the problem will go away.

Also:

- don't use static variables.

Comment: but it's a requirement :(

Comment: @TheEyesHaveIt: then post your requirements. Your question is very incomplete and this has us struggling to understand it and to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance *in the OOP sense* has nothing to do with the code that is in a class's constructors. In fact it's the opposite; variables declared outside the constructor and other methods *are* inherited, and variables declared inside the constructor are *not* inherited.

However, yes, objects added to a Component or JComponent in its constructor will be "inherited" by subclasses (but not in the OOP sense of the word inheritance), unless they are removed in the subclasses. So a quick, somewhat hacky way to fix this would be to remove them again by calling `remove` in the subclasses.

<strike>That's not how I would do it though. A better way might be to call a method `createButtons` in the superclass, and override it in the subclasses to do nothing, but be careful not to refer to anything before it exists if you do it that way.</strike>

But based on the code you've now posted, I don't think it makes sense to use inheritance here at all.

Comment: *variables declared outside the constructor are inherited* you mean class fields, right?

Comment: *So a quick, somewhat hacky way to fix this would be to remove them again by calling remove in the subclasses* IMO a real solution would be to not use inheritance at all but use composition instead, OP should first learn about inheritance and then learn how to apply for this case.

Comment: Yes, it's possible that inheritance is not the right solution for this case.

Comment: I'm trying to think if I can count on one hand the number of times I've subclassed one of my own GUI classes. It's just not often an appropriate thing to do.